# How are wizards buried after they die?

Tags: harry-potter

Do they have some kind of a magical funeral or are they buried in a usual muggle cemetery?

Comment: Burned at the stake? :o)

Comment: Well considering Dumbledore just got buried in Godrics Hollow, seems likely it's just a normal muggle cemetery.

Comment: @Edlothiad didn't Dumbledore get a fancy tomb near the lake? The Potters were buried in Godric's Hollow.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, bare in mind I've never read the books, but I though Dumbledore was buried in the cemetery where they were attacked by Nagini in the house? In one of the Deathly Hallows?

Comment: No, those were Potters. Remember that [Voldy gets the Elder Wand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZzlnIuYfMk) from Dumbledore's tomb near Hogwarts. [This was asked here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154069/where-was-dumbledores-tomb-placed)

Comment: I'm waiting for the punch-line...

Comment: @n00dles - Reluctantly! (Ba-doom tish).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that there is no specific ritual. Lily and James were buried in a more or less normal graves in Godric's Hollow:

[image: Lily and James' tombstone]

Harry Potter Wikia, where this image comes from, also [states that](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/James_and_Lily_Potter%27s_grave) Ignotus Peverell (the original owner/creator of Harry's Cloak of Invisibility), as well as Ariana and Kendra Dumbledore lay in the same cemetery.

[Same Wikia also notes](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/St_Jerome%27s_graveyard) that the St. Jerome's graveyard, where the mentioned persons lay, is for both Muggles and Wizards.

Alternatively, wizards can be cremated, along with their wands, as [ThruGog points out in their answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120731/70236).

However, Dumbledore had a special funeral ceremony (image from Pottermore):

[image: Dumbledore funeral]

and a tomb on Hogwarts grounds, [next to the lake](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154069/where-was-dumbledores-tomb-placed):

[image: Dumbledore's grave]

Comment: I may be wrong but I think the questioner may have been asking about the ceremonies, not the tombs.

Comment: @TheDarkLord _"buried in a muggle cemetery"_ is what I was guided by.

Comment: Ah yes, now I remember!

Comment: There is evidence that they can be cremated - I gave an answer about wands burning because there was evidence that they could be buried or cremated with their owners.

Comment: @ThruGog it's been a while since I've held the books or watched the films

Comment: @Gallifreyan - This is not a criticism, I was suggesting you might like to add this point to a good answer.

Comment: @ThruGog which answer do you mean? I'll look into it

Comment: @Gallifreyan - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120727/can-wands-burn

Comment: @ThruGog thanks! I'm out of votes for today, but I'll upvote you tomorrow!

Comment: @Gallifreyan, not all heroes wear capes!